# FillPolygon with holes

Tags: vb.net, graphics, drawing, polygon

I want to create a "fill" that fills the inside of a polygon, created using a point list, but be able to remove its holes.

My old code:

```
Private Sub DrawSomething(ByVal points as List(of Point), _
ByVal myBrush As System.Drawing.Brush, _
ByVal myGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics)
  myGraphics.FillPolygon(myBrush, points)
End Sub
```

It simply fills a polygon created by the contour of the points in the list.

How can I fill the polygon, but exclude the holes in it (which I know are inside, I have tested):

```
Private Sub DrawSomething(ByVal points as List(of Point), _
ByVal holes as List(of List(of Point)), _ 
ByVal myBrush As System.Drawing.Brush, _
ByVal myGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics)

' fill the contour created by points, excluding the contours created by holes
End Sub
```

Is there something I can use, that has already been created ? Can I somehow draw the original polygon and remove the holes ? What would be the best approach ?

What have I tried - example: I have done the following:

```
Private Sub DrawSomething(ByVal points as List(of Point), _
ByVal holes as List(of List(of Point)), _ 
ByVal myBrush As System.Drawing.Brush, _
ByVal myGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics)

  Dim myGraphicsPath As Drawing2D.GraphicsPath = New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath(Drawing2D.FillMode.Winding)
  myGraphicsPath.AddLines(points)
  Dim myRegion As System.Drawing.Region = New System.Drawing.Region(myGraphicsPath)
  Dim otherGraphicsPath As Drawing2D.GraphicsPath = New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath(Drawing2D.FillMode.Winding)  
  ForEach otherPoints as List(of Point) in holes
    otherGraphicsPath.AddLines(otherPoints)
  Next
  myRegion.Exclude(otherGraphicsPath)
  myGraphics.FillRegion(myBrush, myRegion)

End Sub
```

This is not so bad... it does exclude the inner polygons, but it also draws a swath of "empty" between the contours. So, I guess it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Edit: Adding picture: [image]

The contour is given as a list of points ("points"), the holes as a list of lists ("holes").  The picture on the right has a rough drawing of the swaths of lines that I get (even though the holes and the contours have no points in common) - the lines change as I move the image.

Comment: Not sure I understand where the problem is.  Can't you just draw the polygon again without the holes?

Comment: That is all I want. Draw the polygon, without the holes. The fact that there are holes inside the polygon is essential information. So I can't just cover them up. I have all the information, theoretically - I just don't know how to draw it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using StartFigure and CloseFigure on your GraphicPath objects:

```
For Each otherPoints as List(of Point) in holes
  otherGraphicsPath.StartFigure()
  otherGraphicsPath.AddLines(otherPoints)
  otherGraphicsPath.CloseFigure()
Next
```

Without that, I think all of your objects are connecting to each other.

Comment: I also tried to create separate regions for each figure, and exclude them. with the same effect.

Comment: @Mihaela I can't dupe it otherwise.  Double check the values in your holes collection.

Comment: Found my bug - it was in the actual processing of holes... Thank you for the help.