# GMAP.NET polygon with hole

Tags: polygon, gmap.net

I just want to draw a region (a polygon) with just 2 holes inside.
I am completely unable to ''translate'' the answer of [question 15077148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077148/fillpolygon-with-holes) working with GMAP.Net : I cannot imagine it is impossible. 
Tnaks in advance 
P.

Answer (score 0):

There's no build in way of doing this, I'm afraid. However nothing stops you from drawing those holes on your own within the same polygon.

The approach to adding a hole is simple:

- pick one outer point an duplicate it
- from the first one you move on to a nearby inner point ("the hole") of the inner polygon and duplicate this one as well
- now draw the inner one counterclockwise (by turning around the order of the coordinates) and return to the duplicated outer one

This effectively creates a seam, you can abstract away this functionality in a separate method that takes the coordinates of the outer polygon and an arbitrary number of "hole" polygons. The minor difficulty is to find the nearest inner point to create the seam.

To explain further you end up with the following sections:

- `AB BC CD DA` for the polygon
- now you pick one point, let's say `C` and duplicate it -> `C'`
- now you'll have to find the closest point of the inner polygon `EF FG GH HE`, let's pretend this is F, duplicate this one -> `F'`
- following the above you now
  pass into the polygon this range of points: `A B C F E H G F' C' D`

This algorithm assumes that both fed in polygons are constructed clockwise, which is something you can manage I guess.

Comment: Pefectly detailed . The only ''bad'' (but not too) point is that the border CF (and F' C' (the same)) will appear in the map. I have also a sub routine which is able to create a single polygon as the union of a set of polygons (in the case they are all connected) => your solution seems to be easyly adapted .

Comment: Sounds good, you could go for an additional polygon of the outer one just drawing the border and then only have the fill on the one with the hole.

Answer (score 0):

1. draw two polygons side by side
2. set both of them unfilled (or filled with white or 100% transparent)
3. let the borders of both be thick enough so they 'overlap'

easy~~~